# A binary quadratic form: $nx^2-y^2=2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are there $(x, y)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ such that $nx^2-y^2=2$ ?

Comment: [Related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Transformations).

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by J.Claus and JavaMan, the Pell-like equation,

$$u^2-nv^2=-2\tag{1}$$

has solutions when $n$ is a prime of form $p=8m+3$ (by Legendre). Another class obviously is,

$$u^2-(m^2+2)v^2=-2$$

A third class seems to be $n = 2p$, with $p$ the same primes above, but I have no ready proof.

A fourth is $n=3+2a+7a^2-6a^3-3a^4-4a^5+4a^6$, so,

$$(5+9a+15a^2+2a^3-4a^4-8a^5)^2-n(3+4a+4a^2)^2 = -2\tag{2}$$

**Excluding** $a=0,1$, I believe the parameterization above gives the fundamental solutions of $(2)$. There are other polynomial solutions to Pell equations in my [site](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/008) (in fact $(2)$ is a member of a 2-parameter family), and the transformations given in Wikipedia are from this site as well.

Comment: I am not sure this works when $\Bbb Q(\sqrt p)$ isn't a PID.

Comment: You mean for the third class? Well, (eq.1) is solvable for $n=2p$ for the first 50 primes $p=8n+3$. But if it does fail, it should be good to know the first $p$.

Comment: The $n=2p$ case follows from an old result of Nagell; it does not depend upon the class number of the corresponding fields.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very similar to Pell's Equation and luckily it's already been studied, such as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Transformations).

Go through their listed transformations to arrive at $$ \left(y^2 + 1\right)^2 - n(xy)^2 = 1 $$ I'm not sure how to proceed from here, as Pell's Equation doesn't have a closed form for the fundamental solution and so it can't easily be said if one of the the solutions will be in the form $ y^2 + 1 $.