# Seeking references on the special Pell equation $X^2 - abY^2 = a$

Tags: reference-request, pell-type-equations

The title says it all: I would like to find out more about the special case
$$X^2 - abY^2 = a$$
of the generalized Pell equation
$$X^2 - DY^2 = N.$$
I have found a lot of literature about the Pell equation, of course, but nothing which focuses on this special case.

Comment: This s equivalent to the question Does $ax^2 - by^2$ integrally represent $1?$ If it does, it is (equivalent to) the principal form $u^2 - ab v^2.$ If not, well, no.  Just a few cases in Buell, even if $a,b$ are prime you quickly get quartic residues.

Comment: Is http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387970370 the Buell to which you refer?

Comment: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387970370  must be, although your link did not work for me

Comment: Fixed. (and Thanks!)

Comment: On of the more well-studied special case is $x^2-2py^2 = \pm 2$. If $p=8m+3$ is prime, then it has solutions for $-2$. If $p=8m+7$ is prime, then it has solutions for $+2$. These are by Legendre and Nagel. See also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395615/a-binary-quadratic-form-nx2-y2-2).